# HMS Ads Kit - Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.29.303

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Actually i was trying to implement ads but i did everything with instruction of codelab but this message is showing .... how can resolve this problem.??

**ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.29.303.**

Thanks

Comment: can you tell please did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added this plugin in top of your app build.gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect
```

Also make sure you have added below code in top-level build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your top level build.gradle looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIOia.png)

After that, verify you are not using proxy settings:

Go to Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings ->HTTP Proxy

Finally go to File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeP3P.png)